# PHP form action not redirecting

Tags: php, forms, action

I developed a web crawler to search for certain tags on my companies websites to make sure they are live, have Google analytics, blah blah. However, my company has close to a hundred websites so the actual crawl process, is literally a crawl. So I wanted to create a form where the user inputs a web address of one of our companies and it only crawls that one website. I am not good with forms, so what I basically want the form to do is store the url the user inputs then redirect to a different page where the url is given to the crawler and the results are shown.
Here is basically what I have so far, not much, I am having trouble redirecting to a different page and storing the URL variable so I can pass it to the crawler code that I have.

```
<div id="main-content" class="mc-left"> <div class="entry"> <div style="position:absolute; margin-left:520px; height:25px; width:120px; font-size:10px;"> </div>
</div>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="submitcrawler.php">
    <div class="hiddenfields">
    <p>Website Address:<br>
    <input name="websiteaddress" type="text"></p>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit">          
</form>
```

As you can see I want this form to bring me to submitcrawler.php, however, when I create that php file, when I hit submit it brings me to the current slug (../crawler-2/submitcrawler.php instead of ../submitcrawler.php) so it throws up a 404 error

Comment: did you tried `../submitcrawler.php`

Comment: Yes worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is submitting to 'submitcrawler.php' in the same folder as the file that you're looking at, so if its in /crawler-2/ then that's where its looking.

Use ../ if you want to ascend to the directory above, or probably better, use / and enter the path to the file from the web root (the top directory viewable by apache / the web server).

So

```
<form action="../submitcrawler.php">
```

or

```
<form action="/submitcrawler.php">
```

Answer (score 1):

For the functionality that you're looking for, you could try using `method="GET"`. That way, you can see the information that is being passed to the other PHP script in the URL.

Then simply retrieve the information in the other PHP script:

```
if(isset($_GET['websiteaddress'])) {
    $websiteaddress = $_GET['websiteaddress'];
} else {
    echo "No web address was received.";
}
```

In terms of the form `action` attribute, you need to use an *absolute path* if the scripts will both be static, otherwise if the scripts are dynamic and may change locations on the servers, then use *relative paths*.

Path Info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the file you're talking about is under crawler-2 directory it will submit the form to that file unless you use a relative path `../submitcrawler.php`

Answer (score 0):

The action you have set on that form will send it to submitcrawler.php in the same directory as the current script. Try changing the action to ../submitcrawler.php, or alternatively set it to the absolute url of the script (http://mydomain.me/submitcrawler.php)

Answer (score 0):

You used a relative path in your post action value.  If for example your crawler script is in your webroot you should use action="/submitcrawler.php". If not you can do something like  action="/path/to/submitcrawler.php"